How to restrict imputation of a categorical variable to a subset of categories, using mice in R?
I want to perform multiple imputation with chained equations, using the package 'mice' in R. One of the variables that has missing values is categorical with three levels (say A, B, and C). The values that are missing from this variable can in reality only be A or B, but not C. How can I restrict the imputation such that level C is never imputed for this variable?
Toy example here:
require(mice)
set.seed(12345)
N = 50
miss = sample(0:1, N, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE)
miss2 = sample(0:1, N, prob = c(0.4, 0.6), replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(N),
  x2 = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], N, replace = TRUE)),
  x3 = rnorm(N)
)
df$x2[miss==1] <- NA
df$x3[miss2==1] <- NA


imp = mice(df, m = 2)
imp1 = complete(imp, 1)
imp2 = complete(imp, 2)
dfx2 = data.frame(df$x2, imp1$x2, imp2$x2)
dfx2[is.na(dfx2$'df.x2'),] 

   df.x2 imp1.x2 imp2.x2
10  <NA>       C       C
20  <NA>       A       C
23  <NA>       B       B
38  <NA>       C       C
43  <NA>       B       B

So mice imputes x2 as either A, B, or C, as it "should" - but I'd like to restrict the imputation to only either A or B.
I've looked at this: https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/224#issuecomment-693935305 - but there the restriction is conditional on another variable in the data set. In my case, the restriction applies for all missing values of x2.
This question: Imputing a categorical variable with MICE but restricting the possible values is very similar to mine. The proposed  solution there was to remove from the data frame all rows where the variable-to-be imputed has the category we don't want to impute (ie, in my toy example to remove all rows where x2=="C"), then impute, and afterwards add those rows to the data frame again. This does not work in my case, however, as my data also feature other variables with missing values, which then would not be imputed (cf variable x3 in my toy data set).

It's a bit cumbersome, but I think you can use the main idea from the other answer - keep only the observations where the values you want are present in the categorical variable.  However, you'll need to take a couple of more steps.  Below, I just added another variable with missing data to see how it works.
require(mice)
set.seed(12345)
N = 50
miss = sample(0:1, N, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE)
miss2 = sample(0:1, N, prob = c(0.4, 0.6), replace = TRUE)
miss3 = sample(0:1, N, prob = c(0.7, 0.3), replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(N),
  x2 = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], N, replace = TRUE)),
  x3 = rnorm(N), 
  x4 = runif(N)
)
df$x2[miss==1] <- NA
df$x3[miss2==1] <- NA
df$x4[miss3==1] <- NA

First, identify the places where the variable of interest x2 is missing in the data.
w2 <- which(is.na(df$x2))

Do the imputation as you would for the entire dataset.  This will impute x2, in an unrestricted way for now, but that's alright.
imp = mice(df, m = 2)
imp1 = complete(imp, 1)
imp2 = complete(imp, 2)

Re-impose the missingness on x2 in all completed datasets.
imp1$x2[w2] <- imp2$x2[w2] <- NA

Identify the values where x2 is the unwanted imputation value.
x2c <- which(df$x2 == "C")

For each completed dataset, make two subsets - one that has NA and usable values of x2 and one that has the unusable values of x2.
imp1c <- imp1[x2c, ]
imp2c <- imp2[x2c, ]
imp1_notc <- imp1[-x2c, ]
imp2_notc <- imp2[-x2c, ]

Make a single imputation for each of the completed datasets that has NA and usable values of x2 and generate a new completed dataset for each one.
imp1b <- mice(imp1_notc, m=1)
imp2b <- mice(imp2_notc, m=1)

comp1_notc <- complete(imp1b)
comp2_notc <- complete(imp2b)

For each completed dataset, append the part that had unusable values for x2 to the bottom.
comp1 <- rbind(comp1_notc, imp1c)
comp2 <- rbind(comp2_notc, imp2c)

This shows that the marginal distribution of x2 increases only in B in the imputation.
> table(df$x2, useNA="ifany")

   A    B    C <NA> 
   9   17   19    5 
> table(comp1$x2)

 A  B  C 
 9 22 19 
> table(comp2$x2)

 A  B  C 
 9 22 19 

This will work in the sense that it produces imputations that have the values you want.  The only thing to be slightly concerned about is that the imputations for x3 and x4 are now conditioned on the initial imputation that permitted C as a plausible value.  Might be worth asking on CrossValidated whether the solution I proposed would have the right statistical properties.
